# iOS 7+, store Remote/Push Notifications locally in a database

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Im using [Parse](http://parse.com) to send push notifications to my app, i need to store these notifications to show them within notification history screen, the problem is Parse dosent have an API to pull the notifications from Parse's server.

Plus i can't store any notification to the database if the user didn't click on it in the notification centre, because the method: `application: didReceiveRemoteNotification` dosent work unless the notifications was clicked by the user, or the app was working in the foreground.

Ive almost tried everything, any fresh ideas to solve my problem??

Answer (score 1):

Im would suggest saving the notification to the notification history db table before sending it to the user. doing it all on the server side. this way the user will have it saved whether he opened the notification or not.

Comment: When you say "Im using Parse to send push notifications to my app" do you mean you are using their web dashboard to manually send the notifications ? if so then just add that data (also manually) to your DB after every push you send. If you are using server code to send out the notifications (Parse has the option to write server code) then just add the notification to the DB after you send it out.